# Xamarin.iOS UIApperance setDefaultTextAttributes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uikit, uiappearance

I'm trying to figure out how to implement following code in Xamarin:

`[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]     setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]}];`

But I cannot find a way to setDefaultTextAttributes on UIApperance class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a *number* of missing `UIAppearance` features in Xamarin.iOS and in regards to your question, there is a *missing* API.

- This is a bug,  I wrote my own `UIAppearance.cs` to add the missing features and correct the missing API and *assume* no other Xamarin.iOS coders really use  the newer `UIAppearance` features as it has been broken since iOS 9 in Xamarin.

First, `appearanceWhenContainedIn` is deprecated and you should be using `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses` instead.

> AppearanceWhenContainedIn - was deprecated in iOS 9 and is not recommended for use.

Second, `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses` is **incorrectly** defined within `Xamarin.iOS` as ***only available in `tvOS`*** and that is just not true.

```
#if TVOS
   // new in iOS9 but the only option for tvOS
   const string selAppearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses = "appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:";
   ~~~
```

[UIAppearance.cs#L77](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/fc55e4306f79491fd269ca2495c6a859799cb1c6/src/UIKit/UIAppearance.cs#L77)

- Update: I submitted a Github issue regarding this.

  - https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/3230

Thus it is not available via the Xamarin.iOS wrapper API, but of course is available directly from the ObjC runtime as such:

```
var NSForegroundColorAttributeName = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(UIKitLibraryHandle, "NSForegroundColorAttributeName");
var defaultAttributes = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(new NSObject[] { UIColor.Red }, new NSObject[] { NSForegroundColorAttributeName });
var styleHandle = GetAppearanceEx(Class.GetHandle("UITextField"), typeof(UISearchBar));
void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(styleHandle, Selector.GetHandle("setDefaultTextAttributes:"), defaultAttributes.Handle);
```

[image]

The next problem there are a number of Xamarin.iOS methods marked **internal** that are needed for the above code to function, so some copy/paste/modify of some source is needed:

```
public const string selAppearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses = "appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:";

public static readonly IntPtr UIKitLibraryHandle = Dlfcn.dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit", 0);

[DllImport("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib", EntryPoint = "objc_msgSend")]
public static extern IntPtr IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, IntPtr arg1);

[DllImport("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib", EntryPoint = "objc_msgSend")]
public static extern void void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, IntPtr arg1);

public static IntPtr GetAppearanceEx(IntPtr class_ptr, params Type[] whenFoundIn)
{
    var ptrs = TypesToPointers(whenFoundIn);
    var handles = NSArray.FromIntPtrs(ptrs);
    using (var array = handles)
    {
        return IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(class_ptr, Selector.GetHandle(selAppearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses), array.Handle);
    }
}

public static IntPtr[] TypesToPointers(Type[] whenFoundIn)
{
    IntPtr[] ptrs = new IntPtr[whenFoundIn.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < whenFoundIn.Length; i++)
    {
        if (whenFoundIn[i] == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Parameter {0} was null, must specify a valid type", i));
        if (!typeof(NSObject).IsAssignableFrom(whenFoundIn[i]))
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Type {0} does not derive from NSObject", whenFoundIn[i]));

        var classHandle = Class.GetHandle(whenFoundIn[i]);
        if (classHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Could not find the Objective-C class for {0}", whenFoundIn[i].FullName));
        ptrs[i] = classHandle;
    }
    return ptrs;
}
```

Comment: @TunykPavel No problem, glad that it help 

Comment: Wow I was looking into this but got no where close, great job Sushi! 

Comment: @IainSmith LOL...thanks, I wrote a complete replacement for `UIAppearance.cs` for a client some time ago that than had a CSS templating layer on top so I had an advantage of someone else paying me to learn the tricks ;-)

Comment: Sorry for my late question, but how can I use this code to change UILabel NumberOfLInes inside UIAlertController? I need a two line action sheet option...

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática You should ask a new question with what you are trying to achieve and the code you have so far.

Comment: @SushiHangover [could you give me a hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258352/xamarin-ios-action-sheet-line-numbers)?