# Xamarin.iOS - Action Sheet Line Numbers

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uikit, uiappearance

I have this scenario: My action sheets have a variant text size, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215654/uiactionsheet-uialertcontroller-multiline-text), but trying to access this API from xamarin iOS, I cant find the property:

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).numberOfLines = 2
```

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262588/xamarin-ios-uiapperance-setdefaulttextattributes), anwsered by @SushiHangover, there are many hidden API's by Xamarin, and with the code, I think I can achieve the desired behavior.

So, in Xamarin.iOS, how can I force my action sheet's options to have two or more lines of text? I'm not familiar with iOS internals or Objective-C.

I tried to found the Attribute name of this property and try the Sushi's solution, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

Using SushiHangover's solution on his answer, i can achieve the desired behavior using the following code:

```
var styleHandle = IosUtils.GetAppearanceEx(Class.GetHandle("UILabel"), typeof(UIAlertController));
        IosUtils.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(styleHandle, Selector.GetHandle("setNumberOfLines:"), ((NSNumber)2).Handle);
```

I can't affirm if is the best solution, but I can do what I need.